# [centos]Fail to pip install lxml, gcc failure

Tags: python, django, gcc, centos, lxml

I was trying to install aldryn-newsblog through pip, and I found lxml is not working very right. I got

```
Failed building wheel for lxml
```

and

```
Compile failed: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4
```

Then, I tried

```
pip install lxml
```

and I got this.

```
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-3.6.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lxml ... error
  Complete output from command /home/wachiu/wachiuhub/venv/bin/python3.4 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-npudv0ng/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpnso7x66opip-wheel- --python-tag cp34:
  Building lxml version 3.6.0.
  Building without Cython.
  Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
  Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib64
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml
  copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml
  copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml
  copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml
  copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml
  copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml
  copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml
  copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml
  copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml
  copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron
  copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml
  copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml
  copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  running build_ext
  building 'lxml.etree' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/lxml
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/usr/local/include/python3.4m -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
  gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
  Please submit a full bug report,
  with preprocessed source if appropriate.
  See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
  Compile failed: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4
  creating tmp
  cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInitevrwfs06.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInitevrwfs06.o
  cc tmp/xmlXPathInitevrwfs06.o -L/usr/lib64 -lxml2 -o a.out
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for lxml
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
Failed to build lxml
Installing collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
    Complete output from command /home/wachiu/wachiuhub/venv/bin/python3.4 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-npudv0ng/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-lfur6vjg-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/wachiu/wachiuhub/venv/include/site/python3.4/lxml:
    Building lxml version 3.6.0.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
    Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib64
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml
    copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml
    copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml
    copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml
    copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml
    copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml
    copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml
    copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml
    copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml
    copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
    copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/html
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron
    copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml
    copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml
    copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/includes
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/lxml
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/usr/local/include/python3.4m -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
    gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
    Please submit a full bug report,
    with preprocessed source if appropriate.
    See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
    Compile failed: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4
    cc -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /tmp/xmlXPathInitmk0v_o8b.c -o tmp/xmlXPathInitmk0v_o8b.o
    cc tmp/xmlXPathInitmk0v_o8b.o -L/usr/lib64 -lxml2 -o a.out
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/wachiu/wachiuhub/venv/bin/python3.4 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-npudv0ng/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-lfur6vjg-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/wachiu/wachiuhub/venv/include/site/python3.4/lxml" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-npudv0ng/lxml/
```

I am using centos7 on digitalocean, python3.4.4 with virtualenv.

```
dependencies installed:
python-devel
libxml2
libxml2-devel
libxml++-devel
libxslt-devel
libxslt
ruby-devel
gcc
python-setuptools
```

I checked my memory as some say it might be not enough of memory but it seems to be alright.

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            489          84         252          29         152         287
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Thank you. Really need help now.

My result on

```
easy_install lxml
```

I checked the location of easy_install. It is from the virtualenv/bin.

```
Searching for lxml
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/lxml/
Best match: lxml 3.6.0
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/l/lxml/lxml-3.6.0.tar.gz#md5=5957cc384bd6e83934be35c057ec03b6
Processing lxml-3.6.0.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-p1rirwi3/lxml-3.6.0/setup.cfg
Running lxml-3.6.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-p1rirwi3/lxml-3.6.0/egg-dist-tmp-irdbyshx
Building lxml version 3.6.0.
Building without Cython.
Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib64
gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
Compile failed: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4
```

Comment: What is corresponding package name for each of them? I can only install the python-setuptools but not the others. Still cannot install lxml.

Comment: The "easy_install lxml" result: "gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)" and "Compile failed: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4".

Comment: my mistake. the second answer from the link helped me solved the problem. The root cause is not having enough of memory.